# UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason gRpc spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc

I have a problem. I want to receive a http get request on the client, and grpc will send a message to the server, where it will be logged and displayed in the console, however, when I receive a get request, I get this: **io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason**

In the client and server I have a proto folder, in the proto files it says this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.example;
option java_multiple_files = true;
message Hello{
  string message = 1;
}
message Greet{
  string message = 1;
}
service Greeting {
  rpc greeting(Hello) returns (Greet){}
}
```

Now I organized the server in the service, like this:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class GreetingService extends GreetingGrpc.GreetingImplBase {

    @Override
    public void greeting(Hello request, StreamObserver<Greet> responseObserver) {
      log.info("I receive message : " + request);

      Greet grret = Greet.newBuilder()
                      .setMessage("Hello to you too!")
                              .build();
      responseObserver.onNext(grret);
      responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

In my understanding, we write return, for the event: *greeting*. Now, I want to send a request here, for this I wrote a controller in the client:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping
    public void greeting(){
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
                .forAddress("localhost", 9000)
                .usePlaintext().build();

        GreetingGrpc.GreetingBlockingStub stub = GreetingGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
        Greet greet = stub.greeting(Hello.newBuilder()
                        .setMessage("Hello, World!")
                .build());
        channel.shutdown();
    }

}
```

But unfortunately, when I send a GET request to localhost:9010 (my client), I get an error. I really hope for your help.

My pom.xml is in both modules(server, client)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <description>server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>
                        com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.4.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem: I did not have a gRpc server, I tried to catch a connection with the Spring server, it turns out that I need to write it:

```
public class GrpcRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Server server = ServerBuilder
                .forPort(9020)
                .addService(new GrpcServer()).build();

        System.out.println("мы запускаемся");
        server.start();
        System.out.println("мы запустились");
        server.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

There seems to be a dependency called: **grpc-spring-boot-starter**
It will allow you to run the gRpc server with spring, but unfortunately, it is not installed for me..